# ArangoDB: traverse only edges within a time range

Tags: graph, arangodb

I am experimenting with [time based versioning](http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/).
I have created a vertex that is connected to other vertices with this edge on one side:

```
{
  "_id": "edges/426647569364",
  "_key": "426647569364",
  "_rev": "426647569364",
  "_from": "nodes/426640688084",
  "_to": "nodes/426629284820",
  "valid_from": "1385787600000",
  "valid_till": "9007199254740991"
}
```

And this edge on the other:

```
{
  "_id": "edges/426679485396",
  "_key": "426679485396",
  "_rev": "426845488084",
  "_from": "nodes/426675749844",
  "_to": "nodes/426629284820",
  "valid_from": "1322629200000",
  "valid_till": "1417323600000"
}
```

The valid_till value in the first edge is the output of the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` function.

I looked at [custom vistors](http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2015/01/28/using-custom-visitors-in-aql-graph-traversals/) a little and it looks like its focused on filtering vertices rather than edges.

How can I restrict my traversal to edges with a valid_till value between `new Date().getTime()` and `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `followEdges` attribute in a traversal. 
`followEdges` can optionally be a JavaScript function for filtering edges. It will be invoked for each edge in the traversal:

```
var expandFilter = function (config, vertex, edge, path) { 
  return (edge.vaild_till >= new Date().getTime() && 
          edge.valid_till <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);

};

require("org/arangodb/aql/functions").register("my::expandFilter", expandFilter);
```

It can then be used in a traversal like a regular custom filter by specifying it in the `followEdges` attribute of the traversal options, e.g.:

```
LET options = { 
   followEdges: 'my::expandFilter' 
}
FOR doc IN TRAVERSAL(nodes, edges, 'nodes/startNode', 'inbound', options) 
  RETURN doc.vertex
```